Design approach for a card based audio file catalogue dashboard
What is the recommended approach for a design as follows when it comes to colors and spacing. I am looking for feedback.

Is this considered too much white space?
Or should there be more padding / margin?
Are the color usages appropriate? I personally find the dark purple for the audio controls not fitting. Did try with lighter shades and unsure if that fits either.
Does this feels like too much information or intuitive enough to know whats going on?

Initially went with 1 card per row but that was alot of white space thus went with 2 pr row (will be 1 per row in mobile).
Pls share your thoughts. Thank you.


(Adding to Danielillo's answer)
I see several issues:

Card layout lacks cohesion/hierarchy
Low card/background contrast
Lack of secondary color

Here's my suggestion:


I don't think the problem is with the colors, but with the distribution of the items based on their visual weight. If you try to analyze the overall composition, you will see that there is an imbalance in the entire design, very marked by the weight of the colored button. This imbalance makes it difficult to interpret each card as an isolated element.

I recommend studying and implementing the Gestalt laws
Gestalt law of closure:

Natural inclination to perceive incomplete or fragmented visual elements as a complete object


Following this law, according to what is perceived in the image of the question, this is the card: the item with the greatest weight marking the beginning of the card and the other three corners with those with the greatest visual weight in second instance:

If the idea of ​​the design is to maintain a subtle difference in color between the background and the card, look for a way to reinforce the corners that define the limit of the latter. There are many options, it's all about trying.
Gestalt law of common region:

When objects are located within the same closed region, we perceive them as being grouped together


Following this law, according to what is perceived in the image of the question, this is the card:

Gestalt law of similarity:

Elements that have visual similarities, like color, shape, or iconography, can visually be grouped together

I would try to find similar or identical elements that, when repeated, define a pattern of isolated groups, just as happens in e-commerce.

Image source: dribbble
